# Ruby Selenium-Webdriver option to set proxy with Chrome

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, watir, chromium

Does anyone have a solution to setting a proxy in selenium-webdriver with chrome using `add_argument`?

Thank you

Comment: instead of option do you  mean?